# Remainder when $p$ is divided by $6$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

> Let $p$ be a prime. If there is a remainder of $1$ on division of $p$ by $3$, then what is the remainder when $p$ is divided by $6$? why?

I know the remainder is $1$ in both the cases, but I'm not sure how to explain why.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Thank you all, very helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$p=3k+1$$
and since $p$ is odd then $k$ is even hence $k=2k'$ so

$$p=6k'+1$$
and the result follows.

Answer (score 2):

If $p\equiv 1\pmod3$ then either $p\equiv 1\pmod6$ or $p\equiv 4\pmod6$. But if the latter is true $p$ must be even, a contradiction.

Comment: There is one even prime - I think that needs to be specifically excluded for a full solution. After all if it were $-1$ instead of $1$ the answer would be different ...

Comment: Right. The only even prime is 2, which is congruent to 2 modulus 3. Hence the contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the prime-ness of $p$ for a moment, which remainders would be possible? Which of these is impossible for a prime?

Answer (score 1):

It is *not* true in both cases.

If the remainder is 1
on division of $n$ by 3,
then
$n = 3m+1$
for some $m$.

We want to see
what values the remainder $k$
can take
when $n$ is divided by $6$.

In this case
$n = 6j+k$
or
$3m+1=6j+k$
or
$3(m-2j)=k-1$
and we want to choose $j$
so that
$k$ is from $0$ to $5$.

If $m$ is even,
we can choose $j$
so that
$m=2j$
so that
$k=1$.

But if $m$ is odd,
$m-2j$ is never zero,
so the smallest value
for $m-2j$ is one.
In this case,
$k=4$.

Therefore,
if $n$ leaves a remainder of 1
when divides by 3,
then $n$ must leave 
a remainder of 1 or 4
when divided by 6,
and both cases can happen.

However,
if $n$ leaves a remainder of 1
when divided by 6,
then $n$ must leave 
a remainder of 1
when divides by 3.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

- There are only two possible remainders $\bmod 2$, that is $0$ and $1$.
- There is only one prime number with $p = 0 \pmod 2$.
- Knowing the remainders of $p$ for both $2$ and $3$ you can find the remainder for $6$ using the [Chinese remainder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$